# Log of sql queries of specific users

Tags: php, mysql

Connection is created to the database using MysqliDb http://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

```
$sqlConnect =  mysqli_connect($sql_db_host, $sql_db_user, $sql_db_pass, $sql_db_name, 3306);
```

What is the best way to log sql queries from an authorized user who belongs to a specific user group? Obtaining the sign of the relationship of the logged in user to the target group is available at the time of creating the database connection object $sqlConnect.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I guess you could make a table called logs and when you do an SQL query, do another query inserting data such as session username etc